# I have a problem with filtering on an array in typeorm. QueryBuilder returns only the first match it finds

Tags: typescript, many-to-many, nestjs, typeorm, query-builder

Part of the database:

Story entity:

```
@Entity('stories')
export class StoryEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column()
  slug: string

  @Column()
  title: string

  @Column()
  description: string

  @Column({default: 0})
  words: number

  @Column({default: 0})
  pages: number

  @ManyToOne(() => RatingEntity, (rating) => rating.stories, {eager: true})
  rating: RatingEntity

  @ManyToOne(() => FocusEntity, (focus) => focus.stories, {eager: true})
  focus: FocusEntity

  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: StoryStatuses,
    default: StoryStatuses.IN_PROGRESS,
  })
  status: StoryStatuses

  @Column({default: 0})
  favoriteCount: number

  @Column({default: 0})
  followCount: number

  @Column({default: 0})
  viewCount: number

  @Column({default: false})
  isPublished: boolean

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.stories, {eager: true})
  author: UserEntity

  @OneToMany(() => ChapterEntity, (chapter) => chapter.story, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    eager: true,
  })
  chapters: ChapterEntity[]

  @ManyToMany(() => FandomEntity)
  @JoinTable()
  fandoms: FandomEntity[]

  @Column('text', {array: true})
  characters: string[]

  @Column('text', {array: true})
  pairings: string[]

  @ManyToMany(() => TagEntity, {eager: true})
  @JoinTable()
  tags: TagEntity[]

  @ManyToMany(() => UserEntity)
  @JoinTable()
  betas: UserEntity[]

  @Column({type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'})
  createdAt: Date

  @Column({type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'})
  updatedAt: Date

  @BeforeUpdate()
  updateTimestamp() {
    this.updatedAt = new Date()
  }

  @BeforeInsert()
  @BeforeUpdate()
  slugifyTitle() {
    this.slug = slugify(this.title)
  }

  countWords(): number {
    if (this.chapters) {
      this.words = this.chapters.reduce((acc, prev: ChapterEntity) => {
        return (acc += prev.words)
      }, 0)
    }

    return this.words
  }

  countViews() {
    this.chapters.forEach((chapter) => (this.viewCount += chapter.viewCount))
  }
}
```

Tag entity:

```
@Entity('tags')
export class TagEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column()
  title: string

  @Column({default: ''})
  description: string

  @BeforeInsert()
  @BeforeUpdate()
  normalizeTitle() {
    this.title = this.title.trim()
  }
}
```

There is also code like this:

```
const queryBuilder = this.storyRepository
   .createQueryBuilder('story')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('story.tags', 'tags')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('story.fandoms', 'fandoms')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('story.author', 'author')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('story.rating', 'rating')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('story.focus', 'focus')

if (filterQuery.tags) {
   const tags = filterQuery.tags.split(';')
   queryBuilder.andWhere('tags.title IN (:...tags)', {
     tags,
   })
 }

if (filterQuery.excludeTags) {
   const tags = filterQuery.excludeTags.split(';')
   queryBuilder.andWhere('tags.title NOT IN (:...tags)', {
     tags
   })
 }

const storyCount = await queryBuilder.getCount()
const stories = await queryBuilder.getMany()

return {
   stories: await Promise.all(
     stories.map(async (story) => {
       delete story.chapters
       return (await this.buildResponse(story, currentUserId)).story
     })
   ),
   storyCount,
 }
```

If I return a response without applying filters, I get the expected result - all entities from the database:
[without filter response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA9zU.png)

```
...
"tags": [
   {
     "id": 2,
     "title": "AU",
     "description": "test-description"
   },
   {
     "id": 1,
     "title": "Action",
     "description": "test-description"
    }
 ],
...
```

As you noticed, in the array of tags there are two tags with the labels "AU" and "Action", but as soon as I apply filters in the response, only the tag that was specified in the filter is returned:
[filter response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQxND.png)

```
// filter value "AU"
...
"tags": [
   {
     "id": 2,
     "title": "AU",
     "description": "test-description"
   }
 ],
...
```

What could be the problem? I really do not understand

Comment: in `tags.title IN (:...tags)` and with `tags = ["AU"]`, you're saying that you need only the tags with "AU" value in their `title`.

Comment: hmm, it seemed to me that I was looking for stories in which there are tags with the tag "AU"? ```leftJoinAndSelect('story.tags', 'tags')```

Answer (score 1):

As a way around you can join it twice with different alias and filter one of them. It is a bit hacky but gets the job done. Like this;

```
   .leftJoinAndSelect('story.tags', 'tags')
   .leftJoin('story.tags', 'tagsForFilter')

   andWhere('tagsForFilter.title IN (:...tags)', {....
```